# Change width and height of the modal in Bootstrap

Tags: css, modal-dialog

I want to change the width and height of the modal in Bootstrap.
How can I set the max-width of modal to 900px? How can I set max-height of modal to screenheight minus the padding:20px.

I used this code,

```css
.modal-dialog {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 900px;
    height: calc(100vh - 40px);
}
```

But it is not working.

It must be vertically and horizontally centered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since already the modal window is `position`ed `relative`, you can just use this:

```css
.modal-dialog {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
}

.modal-dialog .modal-content {
  height: 100%;
}
```

The above CSS will make the modal to be in `fixed` position and makes it look in the offset of `10px` from the four sides.

**Output: http://output.jsbin.com/kepuximasi**

Comment: can i use display:flex? Cause i need it for occupying the spaces

Comment: @JohnArellano Yes, by all means. `:)`